# Combinations of 7 people out of 30

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

A small kingdom wants to choose their king, his advisor and 5 guards, how many ways are there to choose them? $30 \choose 7$? Why? Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not, because it is not specified who is who. The right answer is $${30\choose 1}\cdot {29\choose 1}\cdot {28\choose 5}$$
That is you first choose the king among 30 people and then advisor among other 29 and finaly 5 guards among 28 people.

---

But you can repair your solution: $$ {30\choose 7}\cdot {7\choose 1}\cdot {6\choose 1}$$
That is you first choose a 7 people among 30 people and then king among choosen and then advisor among other 6 you choose and finaly you are left with 5 people which are to be guards.

Comment: I still don't understand. You say:"Because it is not specified who is who", what does that mean?

Comment: When you choose 7 people we dont know who is king among themand so on...

Comment: But why do we care who is king? We just choose 7 people to work in "the government".

Comment: Well, then you don't need king, advisor and guard...